# Illegal reflective access, Trying to Send email

Tags: java, groovy, ant

I am trying to send email using Groovy, but I am getting an illegal access error when running the file:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (file:/Users/username/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current/lib/groovy-2.5.7.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Here is the file I am trying to run:

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='javax.mail', module='mail', version='1.4.4')
)

def ant = new AntBuilder()
ant.mail(mailhost:'localhost', mailport:25, subject:'Test message') {
    from(address:'example@yahoo.com')
    to(address:'someone@gmail.com')
    message("Test mail sent on ${new Date()}")
}
```

This code came from http://mresetar.blogspot.com/2012/01/using-groovy-to-receive-and-send-mail.html.

Can someone explain why the code is giving the error, and why it is not sending an email? Thanks a lot

Comment: this looks like the "usual" jdk>9 warnings (not errors)

Comment: But it's not sending the message to the 'to' email.

Comment: @sweeper123, I believe there should be a real error if mail not sent. How are you starting groovy? Are you sure about host and port (localhost:25) of your mail server?

Comment: Something in Groovy seems to be hacking into one of Lookup's private constructors. Strange that it is org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7 as I think that is only supposed to be used when on JDK 7.